# Applet not painting

Tags: java, applet, paint

I am having issues with my Applet not painting the required graphics.

For some reason, it updates the coloring in the graphics, as you can see this when it prints, it recognizes the mouse is being moved, the graphics are not null, but it still refuses to paint.

How can this be fixed?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class GameApplet extends JApplet implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -6796451079056583597L;
Graphics2D g;
Image image;
Point p = new Point(-100, -100);

public void init(){
    init(1000, 900);
}

public void init(int x, int y){
    setSize(x, y);
    image = createImage(x, y);
    g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
    //if(Graphic.setGraphic(image.getGraphics())){
    if(g != null)
        System.out.println("Graphics made");
    //}
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, x, y);
    System.out.println(g+", "+ (g != null));
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    //Graphic.paint();
    setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
}

public void update(Graphics g){
    paint(g);
}

@Override
public Graphics getGraphics(){
    return g;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    p = e.getPoint();
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    showStatus(e.toString());
    g.fillOval(e.getPoint().x - 5, e.getPoint().y - 5, 10, 10);
    p = e.getPoint();
    repaint();
}

}
```

Comment: Don't draw directly in the paint method JApplet but rather in the paintComponent method of a JComponent such as JPanel or JComponent itself and add this to the applet's contentPane. Extract your image's Graphics object in the MouseListener and dispose of it when you're done with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my recommendations, do all drawing in a JPanel or JComponent's paintComponent method. Get the image's Graphics object only when you need it and dispose of it when you're done with it.  For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GameApplet2 extends JApplet {
   protected static final int APP_WIDTH = 1000;
   protected static final int APP_HEIGHT = 900;

   @Override
   public void init() {
      try {
         SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               GameAppletPanel panel = new GameAppletPanel(GameApplet2.this);
               getContentPane().add(panel);
               panel.init(APP_WIDTH, APP_HEIGHT);
               setSize(APP_WIDTH, APP_HEIGHT);
            }
         });
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class GameAppletPanel extends JPanel {
   Image image;
   Point p = new Point(-100, -100);
   private JApplet applet;

   public GameAppletPanel(JApplet applet) {
      this.applet = applet;
   }

   public void init() {
      init(1000, 900);
   }

   public void init(int x, int y) {
      setSize(x, y);
      image = createImage(x, y);
      Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
      g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, x, y);
      g.dispose();

      System.out.println(g + ", " + (g != null));
      MyMouseAdapter mmAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
      addMouseListener(mmAdapter);
      addMouseMotionListener(mmAdapter);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
      g.setColor(Color.red);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
   }

   private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

      @Override
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         System.out.println(e);
      }

      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         p = e.getPoint();
         repaint();
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
         applet.showStatus(e.toString());
         Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
         g2.fillOval(e.getPoint().x - 5, e.getPoint().y - 5, 10, 10);
         p = e.getPoint();
         g2.dispose();
         repaint();
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: The back drop is coming in now, I am just failing on drawing components on top :/

Comment: @Legend: I don't understand you. Please explain your problem again with a little more detail if possible.

Comment: Ok, well if I do the dispose directly after the repaint, (In the listeners of course) it only paints the first oval, and none after. If I don't dispose, it keeps every oval there is. The painting method you gave me was great, but this is probably the last issue.

Thank you so much for your help btw.

Comment: I am so sorry for my ignorance, I fixed it and now I can start working on adding Towers, minions etc. I am making a Tower Defense game, but my usual method for Graphics didn't work in this case, I am more of a logical programmer, for example, I write all my code obfuscated, per-release. I usually just do this obfuscated way after it works :P

Answer (score 2):

The "don't paint in top-level containers" still needs attending to, but it was not the immediate source(s) of the problem.  Try this simpler code.

```
// <applet code='GameApplet' width=400 height=200></applet>
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class GameApplet extends JApplet
    implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

Point p = new Point(-100, -100);

public void init(){
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillOval(p.x - 5, p.y - 5, 10, 10);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    p = e.getPoint();
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    showStatus(e.toString());
    p = e.getPoint();
    repaint();
}
}
```

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels (Pete) please why in 1) `public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {` is code line `g2.dispose();`

Comment: @mKorbel: I've always been taught that if you get the Graphics object yourself (i.e., when not obtained from the JVM), you need to dispose of it after done with it to prevent using up resources. Here the Graphics object is obtained from a BufferedImage and thus when done with it, should be released.