# How do I add a point to JApplet?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, japplet

I am trying to add a point into my JApplet, and have been searching google and yahoo for an answer to no avail. Whenever I do

```
public class Chaos
{
  Point p = new Point(75, 25);
  public void frame()
  {
    JApplet applet = new JApplet
    applet.add(p); //error on this line
  }
}
```

Eclipse says "The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the argument (Point)
This may seem like an obvious question to some, I am relatively new to Java/

Comment: What do you mean by "add a point to a JApplet"? Makes no sense since what would an applet do with a Point object? You can add components to the JApplet, ... but what are you trying to achieve with this very strange request?

Comment: Eclipse is right because ``Point`` class is not a subclass of ``Component`` class

Comment: `JApplet applet = new JApplet`  That is not how to create an applet. ..not that it would compile.  This might compile `JApplet applet = new JApplet();`  (but is still not the correct way to create an applet).

Answer (score 3):

Some basic rules:

- The only methods that you can legally call on a variable are methods available to the variable.
- For core Java classes, such as JApplets, these methods are well defined in the Java API.
- If you look up JApplet and all its parent classes in the API, you'll find that there is no add method, `add(Point p)`, that takes a Point parameter, and so the compiler is correct to complain.
- Your main problem with this question is that you tell us the problem, but you don't tell us what you're trying to solve. As I've stated in my comment above, "adding a Point to a JApplet" makes no logical sense. What are you desiring that the applet do with this Point? Change is location? Draw a spot on its window? These details will change the possible solutions that are available to you, and until we know, all we can tell your are general rules such as those I've listed in this post.
- If your goal is to draw on the JApplet, then do your drawing instead in a JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method, and then make that JPanel your JApplet's contentPane. There are several decent tutorials that will show you how to do this.
- Don't use an Applet or draw directly with `paint(...)` as has been suggested by another poster as you lose all benefits of Swing graphics including automatic double buffering for when you want to do animations.
- Per Andrew Thompson, Swing Graphics also gives you: key bindings, tables, trees and formatted text components, PLAFs, a few layouts, access to people that have used it this millennium..
- Here's an example of drawing with a JApplet: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9504941/522444)

Comment: *"..lose all benefits of Swing graphics including automatic double buffering.."* ..key bindings, tables, trees and formatted text components, PLAFs, a few layouts, access to people that have used it this millennium..

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can only add [`Component`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) derived class intances to a `JApplet` (although adding [`JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) derived instances is preferable if you're using a `JApplet`). Eclipse is pointing a semantic error in your code, because the data types (the expected type of the `add` method and the variable type you're passing as parameter) don't match.

If you want to **draw** a point in the applet, you have to override the applet's `paint` method in your code and draw a line one pixel long (or a rect of one pixel size). Something like this :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class test extends JApplet {
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int x = 75;
        int y = 75;
        g.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    }   
}
```

If you're planning to add several points to your canvas, store then in a list, then iterate and draw then in the `paint` method as above:

```
public class test extends JApplet {
    private List<Point2D> points;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        points = new ArrayList<Point2D>();
        points.add(new Point2D.Double(75.0, 75.0));
    };

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        for (Point2D p : points) {
            int x = (int) p.getX();
            int y = (int) p.getY();
            g.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
        }
    } 
}
```

If you really want to treat your point's as [`Component`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html)s, then you can create your own custom Point class that derives from one of the [`JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) existing classes (like [`JPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html)) this is more complex though.

Comment: Please don't suggest he use AWT components. Why suggest that someone use a less-powerful GUI library? What possible benefit would he gain other than to learn a GUI library that's even more out of date than Swing.

Comment: Your observation is valid, although, I wasn't suggesting to replace Swing API for AWT, I was suggesting that for simple test drawing (what I think he is trying to accomplish) to use a simpler canvas, so he can focus in the drawing. I updated the answer deleting that suggestion to avoid misunderstandings.